# Comparing lists to see if answer is lower or higher

Tags: python, list, if-statement, comparison

The first part produces

```
    average = ['2 is the average for mark a', 
       '1 is the average for mark b', 
       '1 is the average for mark c',
       '2 is the average for mark d', 
       '1 is the average for mark e', 
       '1 is the average for mark f', 
       '1 is the average for mark g', 
       '1 is the average for mark h', 
       '1 is the rainfall average for mark i',
       '1 is the average for mark j']
```

Then the second part of the code produces

```
z = [1.2423]
```

im trying now to compare the results of the average to the z list and produce a result. Basically

```
if the integer value for a is greater than z then print greater than
if the integer value for b is less than z the print less than   
if the integer value for c is greater than z the print greater than.
```

Is there a way to simply my code such that it compares all the averages without having to manually type the if statement for each? I.e compare all averages and then print if the average is less than or greater than in one line.

Thanks. This is my last question for the day.

Comment: Have you tried a for loop?

Comment: Your question is rather hard to understand. What does the first block of code have to do with anything? What are `a`, `b` and `c` in the pseudocode in your last block? Why is your second `z` value a one-element list, and does it have any connection to the `z` variable you're finding in the previous block?

Answer (score 0):

With the 'barely there' information you've given here is a solution to your problem. Also, some further study wouldn't go astray. You'll get there. Keep at it.

```
average = [a list of your data averages]
z = 1.2423 # z variable doesn't need to be a list, just an int


for i in average:
   if int(i) > z:
       print "greater than"
   elif int(i) < z:
       print "less than"
   else:
       print "equal to z"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> z = 1.2423
>>> [{-1: 'less than', 0: 'equal to', 1: 'greater than'}[(x > z) - (x < z)] for x in [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]]
['less than', 'less than', 'greater than', 'less than', 'less than', 'greater than', 'greater than']
```

If you're running 2.x then the math in the square brackets can be replaced with `cmp(x, z)`.